# Java ArrayList new elements not creating

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create ArrayList with elements from Database. I can get data from DB without any problem, but my problem occurs when I'm trying to create ArrayList of objects. It just doesn't exist. I've declared my list in my main class like this:

`private static ArrayList<Vertex> vertexList = new ArrayList<Vertex>();`

In my `getData()` function shown below

```
private static void getData() throws SQLException{
    result = query.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM GTABLE ORDER BY X,Y");
    while (result.next()){
        int x = result.getInt("X");
        int y = result.getInt("Y");
        float p = result.getFloat("P");
        System.out.printf("X:%d\tY:%d\tP:%.3f\n",x,y,p);
        addData(x,y,p);
        addData(y,x,p);
    }      
}
```

I'm getting all the data from database. Everything works fine until I get to my function `addData(x,y,p)` shown below:

```
private static void addData(int x, int y, float p){
    Edge edge;
    int tmp;

    Vertex vertex = new Vertex(x);
    edge = new Edge(x,y,p);
    //vertex.edgeList.add(edge);
    tmp = ifVertexExists(vertex);
    if(tmp < 0){
        vertexList.add(vertex);
    } else {
        //vertexList.get(tmp).edgeList.add(edge);
    }
}
```

It just doesn't create anything in my list. I've checked it with `isEmpty()` and it it was empty.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT** Here's my `Vertex` class:

```
class Vertex{
private final int vertID;


public Vertex(int x){
    this.vertID = x;
}

public int getVertID(){
    return vertID;
}}
```

`ifVertexExists`

```
private static int ifVertexExists(Vertex vL){
    for(Vertex v : vertexList){
        if(v.getVertID() == vL.getVertID()){
            System.out.printf("Vertex is on the list\n");
            return -1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No vertex with this ID\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Right now, I can create the list and it works well, the vertex are shown on screen, `tmp` is -1. It was bad `ifVertexExists`, thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Please post a complete, verifiable, minimal example. This is some code that anyone can simply *copy-paste* and run immediately, to see the same problem.

Comment: What does `ifVertexExists` do?  What is the result of `tmp`?  Try adding some `System.out.println` statements to see the flow of the program and use a debugger to inspect the variables at runtime

Comment: Can you show the other functions you're using?  What does ifVertexExist(v) look like?

Comment: why are all your methods static?

Comment: @Adam P Please add the definition of `ifVertexExists`. Also, there is no call to `add` on `vertexList`.

Comment: My bet is `ifVertexExists` is always returning >= 0. You should log/ debug that.

Comment: All I can see that `if(tmp < 0){` is never true thats why your arraylist is empty,

Comment: @10sw33 actually a common cause of these sorts of problems is that the program created than one ArrayList object, and added elements to one, and then checked the length of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the response from ifVertexExists is always > 0. Use a debugger or insert print statements to verify this.

Answer (score -1):

I think your vertex class needs to implement `equals` to be used with `ArrayList.contains` which you might be using in `ifVertexExists`.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I updated the comment after reading his EDIT. It seems that I need 50 reputation to comment. In fact, this was my first answer in SO to earn some of them.

Comment: This qualifies as an answer now. Good work. Next time, though, please don't break the rules just because that's the only way to do what you want.

Comment: "You last voted on this answer 10 minutes ago. Your vote is now locked in unless the answer is edited" - typical SO coding, the answer *was* edited.